# Programa que usa input().split(" ") e não roda no Python 3.5.1

Tags: python

Tenho que fazer vários exercícios em Python que os valores de entrada devem ficar na mesma linha e me indicaram o `input().split(" ")`, mas o programa não roda, dá erro. Ex.:

```
C, Q = input().split(" ")
C = int(C)
Q = int(Q)

if(C==1):
    T=4.00
elif(C==2):
    T=4.50
elif(C==3):
    T=5.00
elif(C==4):
    T=2.00
elif(C==5):
     T=1.50
print("Total: R$ %.2f"%(T*Q))
print
```

O erro q dá:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/ILDA/Desktop/lanche.py", line 1, in 
>       C, Q = input().split(" ")
>   ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Answer (score 4):

Isso está acontecendo porque você está tentando fazer um `unpacking` de uma lista (no código `C, Q = input().split(' ')`) porém, no seu unpacking vocês está esperando 2 valores ou mais ("C, Q"), mas acredito que você deva estar passando apenas uma palavra na command line (exemplo "foo"), por isso ira subir essa exceção. Veja como o unpacking funciona:

```
>>> x, y = [1, 2]

>>> x, y
(1, 2)

>>> x, y = [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
need more than 1 value to unpack
```

A relação com o numero de palavras é porque o código `split(" ")` ira retornar uma lista de strings a partir de uma determinada string, exemplo:

```
>>> "foo bar".split(" ")
['foo', 'bar']

>>> "foo".split(" ")
['foo']
```

Em resumo, o código funciona mas está inseguro da forma como foi feito.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui são quatro formas que conheço para que você possa colocar um valor um ao lado do outro:

```
C, Q = input('Digite algo: ')
lista = [C, Q]

Q = int(Q)
C = int(C)
#Primeira forma - Utilizando a vírgula, bem simples.

print(C,Q,'- primeira forma\n')
#Segunda forma - Transformando as variáveis em str e usando o + para unir, simples também.

print(str(C)+str(Q),'- segunda forma\n')
#Terceira forma - Tirando a quebra de linha do print(), é algo bem legal também e as vezes útil.

print(C,end='')
print(Q,'- terceira forma\n')
#Quarta forma - Pegando os valores de uma lista e unindo(transformando em str, ou int no caso.)

print(''.join(lista),'- quarta forma\n')

if(C==1):
    T=4.00
elif(C==2):
    T=4.50
elif(C==3):
    T=5.00
elif(C==4):
    T=2.00
elif(C==5):
    T=1.50
print("Total: R$ %.2f"%(T*Q))
```

Espero ter ajudado.
E como já foi dito, o split serve para transformar uma string em lista, semelhante ao .join que utilizei acima.

Answer (score -4):

O único erro que percebi é a saída, pois esse formato é trabalhado em C e não em Python

forma errada
print("Total: R$ %.2f"%(T*Q))

forma Correta
print(f"Total: R$ {(T * Q):.2f}")

Comment: Não é errada, essa sintaxe é perfeitamente válida no Python, embora já não seja mais encorajada o uso.